# How to save a georeferenced image in jpeg2000 in qgis?

Tags: qgis, gdal, georeferencing, jpeg-2000

I'm georeferencing an jpeg2000 image in qgis, but qgis is only capable to save it in geotif, but gdal would be able to save it in jpeg2000. How should i modify this script:
"gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 27915.9 20968.3......(ect...) "D:/HTI_NEMETORSZAG_jpeg/HTI_NEMETORSZAG/BIVa_0854/Elsass_lothringen.jp2" "C:/Users/~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Elsass_lothringen.jp2"
gdalwarp -r near -order 2 -co COMPRESS=NONE  "C:/Users/~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Elsass_lothringen.jp2" "D:/HTI_NEMETORSZAG_jpeg/HTI_NEMETORSZAG/BIVa_0854/Elsass_lothringen_ref.tif""

It would be 100gbs in gtif...